# Linker (ld v2.23.2 from MinGW) error at form: -L<SOMEDIR> -l<lib1 -l<lib2>,

Tags: c++, windows, linker, mingw, import-libraries

Have ld v2.23.2 from mingw-builds 4.8.0 32bit suite. In my project in a directory there are libs: libitpp.a and libitpp.dll.a. The first is simply static lib, the second is import library to correspondent shared lib (DLL on Windows).

I tell linker to link there libs in following form:
-L$$ITPP_DIR/libs -litpp
and the linker always chooses the second lib (libitpp.dll.a), but I want the first (libitpp.a), because "-litpp" matches it exactly.

At explicit instruction:
$$ITPP_DIR/libs/libitpp.a
all Ok.

What are the rules linker use to find libraries at -l"lib" instruction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate question, but rather than berate you for that, I'll just give you the documentation link again: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html#WIN32

The relevant info will be found under the subhead "direct linking to a dll"; notice that ld will always prefer libfoo.dll.a to libfoo.a when both are present, unless you specify -Bstatic for -lfoo, or more generally -static for all such ambiguous -l specifications.