# Error Compiling DetectText c++ program

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, compilation, mingw

I am building an application based on tesseract OCR and opencv. I found a good program in github which perform Stroke Width Transformation (SWT) in images to detect text.

https://github.com/aperrau/DetectText

I need to try this program. I followed the necessary steps, but I get the following error. I have included all the necessary libraries as well.

> .......mingw32/bin/ld.exe : cannot find -lopencv_core
>
> .......mingw32/bin/ld.exe : cannot find -lopencv_highgui
>
> .......mingw32/bin/ld.exe : cannot find -lopencv_imgproc

I have included opencv library to the directory. Any Help Please ?

Comment: Does my recent answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437844/mingw-fftw3-cannot-find-a-library-header-file offer any insight?

Comment: Also, for an understanding of how `-lopencv_core' and friends map to actual library names, see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271479/linker-ld-v2-23-2-from-mingw-error-at-form-lsomedir-llib1-llib2; have you placed the appropriately named libraries in appropriate directories, (either GCC defaults, or specified by -L)?

Comment: any solutions yet? i have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :(